# Yii : difference between findbypk() vs queryRow()

Tags: php, yii

I am new to Yii framework

I need to replace the query

```
$lang = Country::model()->findByPk($this->id);

with 

$sql ="select * from where id=1";
$command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
$lang = $command->queryRow();
```

Is this correct? If it is not correct please tell me the equivalent to query to replace:

```
$lang = Page_Installation::model()->findByPk($this->id);
```

using `cdbconnection`

Thanks

Comment: If you are new, I would suggest you to try the Yii 2. It's even better than Yii 1.

Answer (score 1):

Refer: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand

Try this:

```
$country = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->from('country')
    ->where('id=:id', array(':id'=>1))
    ->queryRow();
```